# Pairing Bluetooth headphones in command line

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, headphones

How do you pair bluetooth headphones without using the GUI? I don't know how to.

I found different method on the internet but nothing works.

I can actually see my headphones with the command : `hcitool scan`

then i try to connect with : `hcitool cc 00:00:00:00:00:00` and `hcitool auth 00:00:00:00:00:00`

I haven't received an error message but my headphones are not working.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10):

I never solved the UI bluetooth manager issue but I got my BT device to connect through the cli (aka terminal).

What worked for me:

1. Make sure you actually have a BT controller on your computer:

```
bluetoothctl list
```

2. Scan for pairable BT devices: this will help you obtain the MAC address of your device. The device has to be in pair mode.

```
bluetoothctl scan on
```

3. Once you've found your device, copy the MAC address.
4. Now you can attempt connecting (replace Xs with the copied MAC at step 3):

```
bluetoothctl connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

You can get the list of bluetoothctl commands by typing:

```
bluetoothctl help
```

Good luck,

Answer (score 8):

from [bluetooth connectivity troubleshooter on blog](https://www.lynxbee.com/scan-pair-connect-to-bluetooth-device-from-ubuntu-from-command-line-using-bluetoothctl/?unapproved=4990&moderation-hash=e32fe6bab7494a946d9dbb74f03b6fca)

- if you don't know the MAC do : `bt-device -l | grep <name of your device>`
- now that you have the MAC connect with: `bluetoothctl connect <MAC HERE>`

Now put this in your profile:

```
alias headphones="until bluetoothctl connect <MAC HERE>; do  echo ...  ; sleep 1; done"
```

** MAC HERE will be the MAC you found in previous steps

It might fail a few times because of bt connectivity and latency of connections but it works after 3 tries for me.

- *Using Ubuntu 19.10 on DELL Latitude*
- *connecting HD 4.50BTNC headphones.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use [bluez-tools](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluez-tools/).

Install it by running `sudo apt-get install bluez-tools`.

Find the MAC address of your device with `bt-device -l` and connect to it with `bt-audio -c 00:00:00:00:00:00`.

Comment: bt-audio is not installed but bluez-tools is installng.

Comment: `bt-audio` should come together with `bluez-tools`.

Comment: What happens when you run `bt-audio -c 00:00:00:00:00:00`?

Comment: The BT-audio program is not yet installed. You can install it by typing sudo apt-get install bluez-tools. I tried to remove and install bluez-tools but the problem is still there.

Comment: That's weird. I installed it gracefully with no errors. What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10...

Comment: There's an open issue for bt-audio missing from bluez-tools https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools/issues/13.

Comment: Can confirm for 17.10 - used apt to install bluez-tools, bluez was already installed, and no bt-audio exists in /usr/bin - where e.g. bt-device can be found

Comment: Same for 18.04, bluez-tools installed but no bt-audio.

Comment: And still not in 19.04. Is there a commandline solution or are we stuck with GUI?

Comment: `pavucontrol` to connect audio playback to the bt output device

Answer (score 2):

### For Ubuntu Users

#### Connect your headphones to Bluetooth in a robust manner.

We will use the `bluetoothctl` command-line utility:

- **Important**: Make sure your device is bluetooth discoverable by pressing some button on the device.
- Find the bluetooth device's MAC-address by running `$bluetoothctl scan on`.

  - This command will start discovering your devices and you need to spot your device's mac address in the output. My device is called "Avi Ear" and it was found in the line:

    - `[CHG] Device 4C:87:5D:9E:04:B8 Name: LE-Avi Ear`
  - From the above output, we know that my device's MAC address is `4C:87:5D:9E:04:B8`.
- Now that we have the MAC address, we can connect to the device with the following bash script **AFTER replacing my MAC address with yours**:

  - **Important**: Before running the script, make sure your device is bluetooth discoverable by pressing some button on the device.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# remove headphones and start fresh
bluetoothctl remove 4C:87:5D:9E:04:B8
# turn bluetooth off
bluetoothctl power off
# turn blutooh on
bluetoothctl power on
# scan for devices for 15 secs so that our device gets discovered.
timeout 15s bluetoothctl scan on
# pair with headphones
bluetoothctl pair 4C:87:5D:9E:04:B8
# trust headphones
bluetoothctl trust 4C:87:5D:9E:04:B8
# connect to headphones
bluetoothctl connect 4C:87:5D:9E:04:B8
```

- Finally, you should see headphones in the "Connected" state in Bluetooth Settings. For example, as you can see in the image below,  "Avi Ear"(Name of my headphones) is "Connected".
  [image]

#### (If no sound) Configure your computer to output to your headphones

Even though my headphones were shown as connected, I did not hear any sound. To hear sound you need to:

- Open the `PulseAudio Volume Control` App. This came preinstalled  with Ubuntu for me, but you should be able to find easy instructions to install if you don't have it.
- Go to the `Configuration` tab and make sure you have all other devices turned off except your headphones like this:
  [image]

You should now be able to hear sounds from your headphones now.

Comment: Underrated answer. Bluetooth implementations are so messy, sometimes my adapter ends up in a weird state where It's impossible to connect through regular GUI interfaces. This worked and I'm saving it for later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on ubuntu 19.04 and executing the following worked for me:
`sudo bluetoothctl <<<"connect $DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS"`
where `$DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS` is the mac address of the bluetooth device.

To find my device's mac address I used `bt-device -l`

Both `bluetoothctl` and `bt-device` commands were already pre-installed on my system.

Hope this can help someone! ;)

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a bluetooth headset, this worked for me.

I installed bluez.

I made sure bluetoothd was running.

I did: bluetoothctl devices

This gave the name and address of my bluetooth device.

I did: bluetoothctl connect

I saw: "Connection successful".

EXAMPLE:

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
Device B8:AD:3E:7B:5E:D2 LG HBS750
$ bluetoothctl connect B8:AD:3E:7B:5E:D2
Attempting to connect to B8:AD:3E:7B:5E:D2
[CHG] Device B8:AD:3E:7B:5E:D2 Connected: yes
Connection successful

the script I now use is simply:

bluetoothctl connect B8:AD:3E:7B:5E:D2
```